# How to read the content of pop up msg which IE shows after submit button

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I have automated data entry in to webpage and in the last when I click submit button it shows one pop up in which the registration no. Generated is displayed.
I want to know is there any way I can copy that registration no and save it in excel.
Please find the pic attached.
[enter image description here][1]
[1]:
I did automated to click on submit button but after that how to read pop up have no idea where to begin, searched a lot on internet but didn't find what I was looking for.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMhX4.png
Please find HTML code on top there is button save named after clicking on which the pop is generated.

```
                        &nbsp;
                    
                        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnOk" value="Ok" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnOk" class="btn" style="display:none;" />
                    
                </div>
                <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UpdateProgress" style="display:none;">
                    
                        <img id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Image1" src="images/loader.gif" alt="Processing" style="border-width:0px;" />
                    
                </div>

            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        

    
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdnVosFlag" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnVosFlag" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdnLNEXP_TYPE" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnLNEXP_TYPE" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdnHDRLNEXP_TYPE" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnHDRLNEXP_TYPE" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdnPFID" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnPFID" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdnpfRefNo" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnpfRefNo" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdnflagNewPan" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnflagNewPan" value="N" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hndchkpan" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hndchkpan" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hndIsStatusEnabled" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hndIsStatusEnabled" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hndRetamt" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hndRetamt" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hndDdlNEFTAcc" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hndDdlNEFTAcc" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hndUsersol" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hndUsersol" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hndneft" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hndneft" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdnAttchmentID" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnAttchmentID" />

    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdnPfLvl" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnPfLvl" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdnvenStatus" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnvenStatus" />

    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabName" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TabName" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdnMode" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnMode" value="I" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$venid" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_venid" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$siteid" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_siteid" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdncrAcc" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdncrAcc" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdnNEFTAcc" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnNEFTAcc" />

    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdnduedtflag" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnduedtflag" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdnpfidindex" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnpfidindex" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdnlstPFids" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnlstPFids" />
    
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdnUserType" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnUserType" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdnDOPLimit" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnDOPLimit" value="1000000" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdn_IFSC_CODE" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdn_IFSC_CODE" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdn_account_id" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdn_account_id" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdnExpenseSolId" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnExpenseSolId" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdnOrgCreationDt" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnOrgCreationDt" />
    

    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdnChkerEin" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnChkerEin" />


    
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
        function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) { var oControl = args.get_postBackElement(); oControl.disabled = true; }

</script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function disposeTree(sender, args) {
            var elements = args.get_panelsUpdating();
            for (var i = elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var element = elements[i];
                var allnodes = element.getElementsByTagName('*'),
                    length = allnodes.length;
                var nodes = new Array(length)
                for (var k = 0; k < length; k++) {
                    nodes[k] = allnodes[k];
                }
                for (var j = 0, l = nodes.length; j < l; j++) {
                    var node = nodes[j];
                    if (node.nodeType === 1) {
                        if (node.dispose && typeof (node.dispose) === "function") {
                            node.dispose();
                        }
                        else if (node.control && typeof (node.control.dispose) === "function") {
                            node.control.dispose();
                        }

                        var behaviors = node._behaviors;
                        if (behaviors) {
                            behaviors = Array.apply(null, behaviors);
                            for (var k = behaviors.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
                                behaviors[k].dispose();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                element.innerHTML = "";
            }
        }


        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoading(disposeTree);

</script>


                                </td>
    </tr>
</table>

                    </div>
                    <!-- #main (end) -->
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- #wrapper (end) -->

        <script type="text/javascript">Cufon.now();</script>

    

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var ctl00_mnuCRM_Data = new Object();
ctl00_mnuCRM_Data.disappearAfter = 500;
ctl00_mnuCRM_Data.horizontalOffset = 0;
ctl00_mnuCRM_Data.verticalOffset = 0;
ctl00_mnuCRM_Data.hoverClass = 'ctl00_mnuCRM_14 hover';
ctl00_mnuCRM_Data.hoverHyperLinkClass = 'ctl00_mnuCRM_13 hover';
ctl00_mnuCRM_Data.staticHoverClass = 'ctl00_mnuCRM_12 statichover';
ctl00_mnuCRM_Data.staticHoverHyperLinkClass = 'ctl00_mnuCRM_11 statichover';

theForm.oldSubmit = theForm.submit;
theForm.submit = WebForm_SaveScrollPositionSubmit;

theForm.oldOnSubmit = theForm.onsubmit;
theForm.onsubmit = WebForm_SaveScrollPositionOnSubmit;
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Sys.Extended.UI.CalendarBehavior, {"format":"dd/MM/yyyy","id":"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox1_CalendarExtender"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtduedt"));
});
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Sys.Extended.UI.AutoCompleteBehavior, {"completionInterval":10,"completionListCssClass":"autocomplete_completionListElement","completionListItemCssClass":"autocomplete_listItem","completionSetCount":20,"delimiterCharacters":"","highlightedItemCssClass":"autocomplete_highlightedListItem","id":"AutoCompleteVenEx","minimumPrefixLength":2,"onHide":"{\"AnimationName\":\"Parallel\",\"Duration\":\".4\",\"AnimationChildren\":[{\"AnimationName\":\"FadeOut\",\"AnimationChildren\":[]},{\"AnimationName\":\"Length\",\"PropertyKey\":\"height\",\"StartValueScript\":\"$find(\\u0027AutoCompleteVenEx\\u0027)._height\",\"EndValue\":\"0\",\"AnimationChildren\":[]}]}","onShow":"{\"AnimationName\":\"Sequence\",\"AnimationChildren\":[{\"AnimationName\":\"OpacityAction\",\"Opacity\":\"0\",\"AnimationChildren\":[]},{\"AnimationName\":\"HideAction\",\"Visible\":\"true\",\"AnimationChildren\":[]},{\"AnimationName\":\"ScriptAction\",\"Script\":\"\\r\\n                                                                                    // Cache the size and setup the initial size\\r\\n                                                                                    var behavior = $find(\\u0027AutoCompleteVenEx\\u0027);\\r\\n                                                                                    if (!behavior._height) {\\r\\n                                                                                        var target = behavior.get_completionList();\\r\\n                                                                                        behavior._height = target.offsetHeight - 2;\\r\\n                                                                                        target.style.height = \\u00270px\\u0027;\\r\\n                                                                                    }\",\"AnimationChildren\":[]},{\"AnimationName\":\"Parallel\",\"Duration\":\".4\",\"AnimationChildren\":[{\"AnimationName\":\"FadeIn\",\"AnimationChildren\":[]},{\"AnimationName\":\"Length\",\"PropertyKey\":\"height\",\"StartValue\":\"0\",\"EndValueScript\":\"$find(\\u0027AutoCompleteVenEx\\u0027)._height\",\"AnimationChildren\":[]}]}]}","serviceMethod":"GetVendorList","servicePath":"/rfp/frmGSTINPaymentformTax.aspx"}, {"itemSelected":SettxtVDName_hiddenValue,"populated":HidevenImage,"populating":ShowvenImage}, null, $get("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtVDName"));
});
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Sys.Extended.UI.CalendarBehavior, {"format":"dd/MM/yyyy","id":"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CalendarExtender1"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtInvoicedt"));
});
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Sys.Extended.UI.CalendarBehavior, {"format":"dd/MM/yyyy","id":"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CalendarExtender2"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtdoa"));
});
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Sys.Extended.UI.AutoCompleteBehavior, {"completionInterval":10,"completionListCssClass":"autocomplete_completionListElement","completionListItemCssClass":"autocomplete_listItem","completionSetCount":20,"delimiterCharacters":"","highlightedItemCssClass":"autocomplete_highlightedListItem","id":"AutoCompleteEx","onHide":"{\"AnimationName\":\"Parallel\",\"Duration\":\".4\",\"AnimationChildren\":[{\"AnimationName\":\"FadeOut\",\"AnimationChildren\":[]},{\"AnimationName\":\"Length\",\"PropertyKey\":\"height\",\"StartValueScript\":\"$find(\\u0027AutoCompleteEx\\u0027)._height\",\"EndValue\":\"0\",\"AnimationChildren\":[]}]}","onShow":"{\"AnimationName\":\"Sequence\",\"AnimationChildren\":[{\"AnimationName\":\"OpacityAction\",\"Opacity\":\"0\",\"AnimationChildren\":[]},{\"AnimationName\":\"HideAction\",\"Visible\":\"true\",\"AnimationChildren\":[]},{\"AnimationName\":\"ScriptAction\",\"Script\":\"\\r\\n                                                                                    // Cache the size and setup the initial size\\r\\n                                                                                    var behavior = $find(\\u0027AutoCompleteEx\\u0027);\\r\\n                                                                                    if (!behavior._height) {\\r\\n                                                                                        var target = behavior.get_completionList();\\r\\n                                                                                        behavior._height = target.offsetHeight - 2;\\r\\n                                                                                        target.style.height = \\u00270px\\u0027;\\r\\n                                                                                    }\",\"AnimationChildren\":[]},{\"AnimationName\":\"Parallel\",\"Duration\":\".4\",\"AnimationChildren\":[{\"AnimationName\":\"FadeIn\",\"AnimationChildren\":[]},{\"AnimationName\":\"Length\",\"PropertyKey\":\"height\",\"StartValue\":\"0\",\"EndValueScript\":\"$find(\\u0027AutoCompleteEx\\u0027)._height\",\"AnimationChildren\":[]}]}]}","serviceMethod":"GetHSNSACList","servicePath":"/rfp/frmGSTINPaymentformTax.aspx"}, {"itemSelected":SetddlTypeValue,"populated":HidehsnImage,"populating":ShowhsnImage}, null, $get("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtHSN_SAC"));
});
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Sys.UI._UpdateProgress, {"associatedUpdatePanelId":"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UpdatePanel10","displayAfter":500,"dynamicLayout":true}, null, null, $get("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UpdateProgress9"));
});
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Sys.UI._UpdateProgress, {"associatedUpdatePanelId":"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_savepnlData","displayAfter":500,"dynamicLayout":true}, null, null, $get("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UpdateProgress"));
});
//]]>
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you could try using selenium basic and switch to alert. Not sure if selenium basic has a getText method though.

Comment: Is this a DOM pop up/Browser Pop-up/Windows Pop-up? if this is a html pop attached with page, please mentions the element in comment from above shared html code.

Comment: @DilipMeghwal I can't help more than that, as I have no knowledge of HTML and how these pop up works I just using VBA to fetch the data in webpage. I have no idea what part of the HTML did that pop up. But one thing I can say when pop comes I can't do any thing in IE unless I click ok

Comment: Are able to inspect that popup using IE developer tool?

Comment: No devloper tool doesn't work on that pop up..after the pop up you can't click anywhere

Comment: Can you run statement `driver.getWindowHandles().size();` after the pop-up open.

Comment: after pop up VBA code stops in background unless click ok in pop up